# writing starting from a certain line number with loop

Tags: scripts

```
echo -n "which names (lower case only)?"
read name
```

let assume inputs are: `brmu ankr ista`

I need to write specific lines after the 20th lines in text file w.r.t. user inputs with one space from the beginning of the line as follows;

```
brmu_gps expt ftprnx
ankr_gps expt ftprnx
ista_gps expt ftprnx
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify. What text file? Do you want to add lines to an existing text file and start at line 20? What should happen to line 21? Should it be removed? What is the "one space" you mention?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Perl:

```
<<<"$x" perl -i -pe 'if($.==21){foreach(split(" ",<STDIN>)){print"${_}_gps expt ftprnx\n"}}' file
```

Perl script expanded:

```perl
if($. == 21) { # if the current line's number is 21
    foreach(split(" ", <STDIN>)) { # splits STDIN on spaces and returns the splitted elements as an array; for each member of the array
        print("${_}_gps expt ftprnx\n") # print the current element followed by `_gps expt ftprnx` and a newline character
    }
}
```

- `<<<"$x"`: reads the input from a variable `x`.
- `-i` in `perl`: specifies that files processed by the "<>" construct are to be edited in-place.
- `-p` in `perl`: causes Perl to assume the following loop around your program, which makes it iterate over filename arguments somewhat like sed:

  ```
         LINE:
           while (<>) {
               ...             # your program goes here
           } continue {
               print or die "-p destination: $!\n";
           }
  ```
- `-e` in `perl`: may be used to enter one line of program.

```
% cat file
line #1
line #2
line #3
line #4
line #5
line #6
line #7
line #8
line #9
line #10
line #11
line #12
line #13
line #14
line #15
line #16
line #17
line #18
line #19
line #20
line #21
line #22
line #23
line #24
line #25
% read x
brmu ankr ista
% <<<"$x" perl -i -pe 'if($.==21){foreach(split(" ",<STDIN>)){print"${_}_gps expt ftprnx\n"}}' file
% cat file
line #1
line #2
line #3
line #4
line #5
line #6
line #7
line #8
line #9
line #10
line #11
line #12
line #13
line #14
line #15
line #16
line #17
line #18
line #19
line #20
brmu_gps expt ftprnx
ankr_gps expt ftprnx
ista_gps expt ftprnx
line #21
line #22
line #23
line #24
line #25
```

Comment: Dear @kos, I applied; echo -n "which names (lower case only)?"  <<<"$(read station; <<<"$station")" perl -i -pe 'if($.==21){foreach(split(" ",<STDIN>)){print"${_}_gps expt ftprnx\n"}}' data_file ; but it doesn't work, I wonder something is wrong?

Comment: @deepblue_86 Did you put `echo -n "which names (lower case only)?"` and `<<<"$(read station; <<<"$station")" perl -i -pe 'if($.==21){foreach(split(" ",<STDIN>)){print"${_}_gps expt ftprnx\n"}}' data` on two separate lines?

Comment: yes @kos, I applied for two separate lines

Comment: @deepblue_86 As of now I can't see the problem. What happens if you remove `-i` from the `perl` command? What's the output?

Comment: all context of data file has been written in terminal with no changes. With -i, the data file is still same without printing the terminal. If you need to see whole context of the data file I can send you for your convenience.

Comment: @deepblue_86 My bad, I tested it in another shell. The quick fix is to split it into two lines, i.e. reading the values with `read x` and then running `<<<"$x" perl -i -pe 'if($.==21){foreach(split(" ",<STDIN>)){print"${_}_gps expt ftprnx\n"}}' data`. That should work.

Comment: thank you very much @kos, it worked now. Last one thing, how can I start to write print"${_}_gps expt ftprnx\n" with one space from the beginning of the line?

Comment: @deepblue_86 Just add a space before `$_`:  `<<<"$x" perl -i -pe 'if($.==21){foreach(split(" ",<STDIN>)){print" ${_}_gps expt ftprnx\n"}}' data`